# Getting Symbols from debugged process MainModule

Tags: c#, debugging, pinvoke, debug-symbols

I started writing a debugger in C#, to debug any process on my operating system. For now, it only can handle breakpoints (HW, SW, and Memory), but now I wanted to show the opcode of the process.

My first attempt was with nidsasm (NASM), but this is not suitable, because after startup a.Net Application assembler instructions are different from ndisasm (tested with CheatEngine).

So I searched a while and found some methods from the dbghelp.dll which can be called to list all loaded modules and symbols (plus the base address). Ok, my attempt is, to disassemble all modules separately with SharpDisasm.

I use `ProcessModuleCollection modules = ProcessData.Instance.MPMR.ReadProcess.Modules;` to get all loaded modules of the process. This works perfectly.

Now I tried to load the symbols of the MainModule, but at this point, I stuck with the implementation. I implemented the SymEnumSymbols Function with p/Invoke and other necessary functions like SymInitialize.

When I call it with a BaseAddress of for example the "User32.dll", all symbols are printed perfectly, but for the MainModule, I didn't get any symbols.

This is a screenshot from CheatEngine:
[Symbols gained from Cheat Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up1Gn.png)

As you can see, there are symbols like "Form1_Load", which I don't get with my implementation.

This is the necessary code sample:

```
if (!DebugApi.SymInitialize(ProcessData.Instance.MPMR.M_hProcess, null, false))
{
    var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    //throw new Exception("GetMemoryInfo failed : GetLastError() : " + new Win32Exception(err).Message);
    Console.WriteLine("GetMemoryInfo failed : GetLastError() : " + new Win32Exception(err).Message);
    return;
}

if (!DebugApi.SymEnumSymbols(ProcessData.Instance.MPMR.M_hProcess, (ulong)ProcessData.Instance.MPMR.ReadProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress, "!", DebugApi.EnumSyms, IntPtr.Zero))
{
    var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    //throw new Exception("GetMemoryInfo failed : GetLastError() : " + new Win32Exception(err).Message);
    Console.WriteLine("GetMemoryInfo failed : GetLastError() : " + new Win32Exception(err).Message);
    return;
}

DebugApi.SymCleanup(ProcessData.Instance.MPMR.M_hProcess);
```

And my DebugApi, with all necessary p/Invoke functions.

```
public class DebugApi
{

    [DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SymInitialize(IntPtr hProcess, string UserSearchPath, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool fInvadeProcess);

    [DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SymCleanup(IntPtr hProcess);

    [DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern ulong SymLoadModuleEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr hFile, string ImageName, string ModuleName, long BaseOfDll, int DllSize, IntPtr Data, int Flags);

    [DllImport("dbghelp.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool SymEnumSymbols(IntPtr hProcess, ulong BaseOfDll, string Mask, PSYM_ENUMERATESYMBOLS_CALLBACK EnumSymbolsCallback, IntPtr UserContext);

    public delegate bool PSYM_ENUMERATESYMBOLS_CALLBACK(ref SYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo, uint SymbolSize, IntPtr UserContext);

    public static bool EnumSyms(ref SYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo, uint SymbolSize, IntPtr UserContext)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Name: " + pSymInfo.Name);
        return true;
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum SymFlag : uint
    {
        VALUEPRESENT = 0x00000001,
        REGISTER = 0x00000008,
        REGREL = 0x00000010,
        FRAMEREL = 0x00000020,
        PARAMETER = 0x00000040,
        LOCAL = 0x00000080,
        CONSTANT = 0x00000100,
        EXPORT = 0x00000200,
        FORWARDER = 0x00000400,
        FUNCTION = 0x00000800,
        VIRTUAL = 0x00001000,
        THUNK = 0x00002000,
        TLSREL = 0x00004000,
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum SymTagEnum : uint
    {
        Null,
        Exe,
        Compiland,
        CompilandDetails,
        CompilandEnv,
        Function,
        Block,
        Data,
        Annotation,
        Label,
        PublicSymbol,
        UDT,
        Enum,
        FunctionType,
        PointerType,
        ArrayType,
        BaseType,
        Typedef,
        BaseClass,
        Friend,
        FunctionArgType,
        FuncDebugStart,
        FuncDebugEnd,
        UsingNamespace,
        VTableShape,
        VTable,
        Custom,
        Thunk,
        CustomType,
        ManagedType,
        Dimension
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct SYMBOL_INFO
    {
        public uint SizeOfStruct;
        public uint TypeIndex;
        public ulong Reserved1;
        public ulong Reserved2;
        public uint Reserved3;
        public uint Size;
        public ulong ModBase;
        public SymFlag Flags;
        public ulong Value;
        public ulong Address;
        public uint Register;
        public uint Scope;
        public SymTagEnum Tag;
        public int NameLen;
        public int MaxNameLen;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1024)]
        public string Name;
    }

}
```

My Functions should be ok, because it works with other Modules (loaded dll's for example). Maybe I don't understand the concept of symbols of a .Net Executable or missing something.

Comment: No, wrong debug engine.  Download the mdbg sample to learn how to debug managed code.

Comment: Good Luck Cedric, the world of debugging requires deep dives into all kinds of stuff not known to the common man.  This is why WINDBG with SOS extension is best.  But even so, that tool takes a while to learn.  If you can improve on that you've got something going here... I agree with Hans that MDBG is the place to start.

Comment: Thank you Hans, I already found the mdbg samples but couldn't find a solution of my problem in the samples. I use the NativeDebugWrappers for my debugger, to call the kernel32 functions for debugging. But for loading symbols from the MainModule of a pe executable (in this example a .Net executable), I didn't found something there, maybe my eyes are tired from a whole day searching trough the internet.

Comment: @Strece I know it's old but still... What do you mean when you say MainModule's symbols? I think information about assembly's classes/functions could be extracted directly from metadata. Symbols are particularly useful when you need to bind executing IL code to your source code, to show current code statement in debugger for example.

Answer (score 2):

can it be that you are looking for System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.ISymbolScope.
Have a look at the class [SymbolAccess](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/3486/debugger-libs/CorApi2/SymStore/SymAccess.cs/), you can use it to gain access to ISymbolScope.GetLocals() that returns ISymbolVariable[] and GetChildren() again returning in this time an array called ISymbolVariable[]

Now another interesting set of reference code samples is the Debugger extension lets you "snif" the values as shown [here](https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/?source=3486/debugger-libs/CorApi2/Extensions/DebuggerExtensions.cs)